# How to read multiple files from server into c#

Tags: c#, file

I want to know how to read multiple (about 500-1000) text files which are located on a server.
So far, I've written code for a program that only reads a single text file.

Here's how I'm currently reading a single file.

```
  public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Reading/Inputing column values



        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
```

**I would like to get rid of the open file dialog box, and let the program automatically read the 500-1000 text files where are located in the sever.**

I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
  for (int i =0; i<numFiles; i++)
  {
     //just use string[] fileLines =File.ReadAllLines()
     //how would i specify the path for multiple files?
  }
```

Questions are then:

1. How would I approach this?
2. How  exactly should I get the number of files? 
   (I'm guessing I'd have to read the server file which contains them.)

Comment: Do you want to recursively open folders starting from a top level folder or read all files located in one central folder?

Comment: There are about 10 folders, I'd like to recursively open them, and then in each folder recursively open the text files.

Basically, Open folder > Loop through all files. Open next folder Loop through all files > continue till last folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to loop through all directories.  Using [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also allows you to use a `foreach` loop so you don't have to worry about the file count.

```
    private static void ReadAllFilesStartingFromDirectory(string topLevelDirectory)
    {
        const string searchPattern = "*.txt";
        var subDirectories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(topLevelDirectory);
        var filesInDirectory = Directory.EnumerateFiles(topLevelDirectory, searchPattern);

        foreach (var subDirectory in subDirectories)
        {
            ReadAllFilesStartingFromDirectory(subDirectory);//recursion
        }

        IterateFiles(filesInDirectory, topLevelDirectory);
    }

    private static void IterateFiles(IEnumerable<string> files, string directory)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Path.Combine(directory, file));//for verification
            try
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(line);   
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                //Handle File may be in use...                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Also note [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides overload that lets you provide a search pattern to narrow the scope of the files.

Comment: Your reply is very helpful but I need a bit more clarification.

1) topLevelDirectory - So this is the path where all of the individual files on the server are located right? Ex: \\servername\filedirectory

2) When I read the files, I only want .txt. How would I ensure this? I'm guessing topLevelDirectory along with some clause of *.txt

Thx

Comment: 3) Shouldn't the 2nd foreach loop be inside the first one?
@P.Brian.Mackey

Comment: 1) Yes. Think of it as a top down search.  2).  Yes, as noted in the last line of the answer.  Updated code. 3).  No it's not necessary.  It might not impact the output either way, but it's far less readable IMO.

Comment: Note that nested `foreach` does negatively impact performance.

Comment: Also, would it make a significant difference if I made the method to public void, @P.Brian.Mackey

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Directory.GetFiles(string path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get all files from a certain directory. You can then use a foreach loop to iterate through all the files in that directory and do your processing.

Comment: You'll have to use the SearchOption overload for GetFiles since there are multiple folders...unless you want to code a separate path for each one :P

Answer (score 1):

How you go about getting your files depends on if they are all located in the same directory of if you'll need to recursively search through a directory and all child directories.  Directory.GetFiles is where you want to start.  It has 3 overloads seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  So you might try something like this:

```
string path = "\mypath\tosomehwere";
string searchPattern = "*.txt";
string[] MyFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Then just loop through the string array and proccess each file as you would normally.

```
foreach (string filePath in MyFiles)
{
      MyFileProcessMethod(filePath)
}
```

`Path.GetFileName(filePath)` will return the individual text file name should you need it for your processing requirements.